Why is the Index Page of my ASP.NET application not found?
I am currently coding on my ASP.NET Core MVC project. Everything worked just fine, until suddenly, as soon as I compile and start the project, the page is not hosted on root anymore (it always tries to open localhost:7053/index.html, which it throws a 404 when called).
I did not change anything on the Program.cs or the HomeController since when it worked.
The only new concept which I try to learn here is OAuth2, I cut out the code for that, becuase, as just stated, it all worked already.
This is my Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
{
    Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
    MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
});

 app.UseHsts();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

//DO NOT CHANGE
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

and that is my function for the Index View:
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

I even tried a reverted GitHub Commit Update, but the error just continues. As soon as I host it, everything just goes fine (it works just fine when deployed). All other Controllers are reachable without any problems when the URL is prompted.
Can someone please help me?
I already tried:

Reverting the Repo and trying an old version
Inserting default code, still does not work
different solutions written on StackOverflow


Can you post your launchSettings.json file too?

After testing the code you provided, the problem you mentioned was not reproduced. You can check whether the launchSettings.json file is configured with the relevant path, and check whether a custom routing configuration has been added to the controller or method.

I use Razor Pages, and I have this problem, it happens becouse u need show new catalog:
Add this to program.cs
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
      options.RootDirectory = "/wwwroot/Pages";
});

ps: "Pages" - catalog with pages
You can read it here

Thank you, but I do not have Razor Pages, I have normal ASP.NET Views (or am I understanding something wrong)

I just found out it is always as soon as I try to implement SwaggerUI

Can you provide the following configurations for SwaggerUI?
